# Using generators to fill/create a numpy array without for loops

Tags: python, numpy, generator

I have a simple generator that performs a random walk, I use a generator to perform a random walk, since I want to run it for some steps, analyze it, and then run some more. Another good reason is because I want to isolate the mathematical model and the simulation.

I wish to use a `numpy array` store the data from generator (that returns a tuple with `time, position, velocity, acceleration`). To accomplish that I create the numpy array previously and in a for loop (with a enumerate), I fill all locations.

My question is, is there any way to avoid the `for loop` at all?

Code goes below.

```
import numpy as np

def random_walk(initial_position = 0, accel = 0, pa=0.25, pb=.5):
    """Initial position (often 0), acceleration, 0 < pa < pb < 1"""
    # Time, x-position, Velocity, Acceleration
    t, x, v, a = 0, initial_position, 0, accel
    yield (t, x, v, a)

    while True:        
        # Roll the dices
        god_wishes = np.random.random()

        if god_wishes <= pa:
                # Increase acceleration
                a += .1
        elif god_wishes <= pb:
                # Reduce acceleration
                a -= .1

        # Lets avoid too much acceleration
        a = np.clip(a, -.5, +.5)

        # How much time has passed, since last update?
        dt = np.random.random()
        v += dt*a
        x += dt*v
        t += dt

        yield (t, x, v, a)
```

Then I create a simulation with

```
rw = random_walk(0, .2, .25, .5)
```

And I run the experiment

```
experiment = np.zeros((1000,4))
for i in range(1000):
    experiment[i] = rw.__next__()
```

That is the `for` loop I REALLY want to avoid. A performance efficient approach is most welcome.

Any hints?

Comment: Sooner or later a `generator` has to run through all its steps, its iterations.  Until you put it in a for loop or list it is just a potential action, not an actual one.  Generators only save memory/time if you string one after another.  Even then the savings are just relative to stringing lists one after another.  They aren't a "vectorized" operation in the `numpy` sense.

Comment: I don't see how to vectorize this function since, my actual problem is a numerical stochastic simulation. I need to know the previous steps to evaluate the next ones I can't see a way to do it. In strict sense, this `random_walk` isn't a pure function, since it depends on `random()`.

Comment: I opted for the generator because I will run the simulation "forever" and just save snapshots when some corner situation occurs. Using the generator I can guarantee that only the previous steps necessary for the simulation are in the memory. All others will be lost,

Answer (score 0):

You could significantly speed up the `random_walk` generator by **not** using `np.clip`.

This benchmark demonstrates the speed-up:

```
import numpy as np

def clip(value, lower, upper):
    return lower if value < lower else upper if value > upper else value

def random_walk(initial_position = 0, accel = 0, pa=0.25, pb=.5, clip_function=np.clip):
    """Initial position (often 0), acceleration, 0 < pa < pb < 1"""
    # Time, x-position, Velocity, Acceleration
    t, x, v, a = 0, initial_position, 0, accel

    yield (t, x, v, a)

    while True:
        # # Roll the dices
        god_wishes = np.random.random()

        if god_wishes <= pa:
                # Increase acceleration
                a += .1
        elif god_wishes <= pb:
                # Reduce acceleration
                a -= .1

        # # Lets avoid too much acceleration
        a = clip_function(a, -.5, +.5)

        # # How much time has passed, since last update?
        dt = np.random.random()
        v += dt*a
        x += dt*v
        t += dt

        yield (t, x, v, a)

from timeit import timeit

def f1():
    rw = random_walk(0, .2, .25, .5)
    experiment = np.zeros((1000,4))
    for i in range(1000):
        experiment[i] = rw.__next__()
    return experiment

def f2():
    rw = random_walk(0, .2, .25, .5, clip_function=clip)
    return np.array([next(rw) for _ in range(1000)])

t1 = timeit(lambda: f1(), number=10)
t2 = timeit(lambda: f2(), number=10)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints on my machine (AMD 2400G, numPy 1.18.3):

```
0.26705767000385094
0.01964799000415951
```

Comment: the randomwalk was a pet example. the original code isn't anything related to random walks, Since the code is too big, the randomwalk code is just a MWE. But thank your comments. I'm more interest in not use `for` loops or `list comprehensions` to evaluate my stochastic math model to fill a numpy array more directly.

Comment: Anyway is good to know that a common `if` is faster than `np.clip` that should be a specialized function.